# jQuery bgColor animation: keep active when going down a sub-menu

Tags: jquery

I am using the [jQuery Color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/color/) to have a menu `fadeIn()` to a background color of white and then `fadeOut()` to transparent.

I know that it is fading out as the hover function is leaving the element that has the animation applied to it but is there a way to keep the background color active on the main menu item when you go down the sub nav list?

I first had this working when my hover overs were in css but from adding a jQuery animation it's now broke.

Can anyone suggest if it's my jQuery or CSS that needs to be implemented more with this issue?

Here is some code to support my question:

Typical Layout of Nav

```
 <ul id="nav-1">
     <li class="<span>Main Nav Link</span>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
           <li>Sub-Nav-1</li>            
           <li>Sub-Nav-2</li>
           <li>Sub-Nav-3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
     <li>Another Link</liv>
  </ul>
```

CSS:
    ul#nav-1 li {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    }

```
ul#nav-1 li span, ul#nav-1 li a {
padding:18px 13px;
font-size:14px;
color:#2e2e2e;
display:block;
}

ul#nav-1 ul.sub-menu {
position:absolute;
top:58px;
list-style: none;   
z-index:1;
text-align:left;
}

ul#nav-1 ul.sub-menu li {
display:block;
margin: 0;
}

ul#nav-1 ul.sub-menu li a { 
border-bottom:1px solid #dbddd4;
background-color:#f2f2f2;
width:220px;
display: block;
padding: 13px 0px 13px 18px;
}
```

Jquery Animation for Background:

```
('ul#nav-1 li span, ul#nav-1 li').hover(function(){
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor: '#FFF'}, 'slow');
}, function(){
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor:"transparent"}, 'slow');
});
```

Comment: you should provide a jsfiddle for this kind of question

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change your selector so that the `mouseleave` event will only trigger once you have left the parent `li`:

```
$('#nav-1 > li').hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor: '#FFF'}, 'slow');
}, function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor: 'transparent'}, 'slow');
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lau9V/18/)

If you only want the animation to occur on the parent (the `li` or the `span`), you'd have to do something a little more elaborate:

```
var $el, $this;
$('#nav-1 > li').hover(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $el = ($this.has('ul.sub-menu').length) ? $this.find('ul.sub-menu').prev() : $this; 
    $el.stop().animate({ backgroundColor: '#FFF' });
}, function() {
    $el.stop().animate({ backgroundColor: 'transparent' });                           
});
```

So check if the hovered element contains a `.sub-menu`, if it does, apply the animation to the element which immediately precedes the `.sub-menu`, if not, apply it to the `li`.

#### [Here's another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lau9V/24/)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use CSS3 to solve this easely.

If you are using SASS:

```
ul#nav-1 li:hover{
   @include transition-property(background);
   @include transition-duration(500);
   background-color: #FFF
}
```

No jQuery needed and this will solve your issue.

Reference: [CSS3 Transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp)